# Ractive JS global observation

Tags: ractivejs

I'm wanting to have multiple Ractive instances bind to the same data.

```
var data = { text:'Old Text'};

var r1 = new Ractive({ el:.., template:..., data:data })
.observe('text', function(value){
    //r1 is not aware the data has been updated
    alert(value);
});


var r2 = new Ractive({ el:.., template:..., data:data })
.observe('text', function(){
});

r2.set('text', 'New Text');
```

Is there a way I can create global key paths so that r1 gets notified?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few options:

Use `.update()` to tell the other instance to update:

```
var r2 = new Ractive({ el:.., template:..., data:data })

r2.set('text', 'New Text');
r1.update(/*'text'*/)
```

You could use the change events to take this a bit further:

```
var r2 = new Ractive({ el:.., template:..., data:data })
r2.on('change', function(e){
   r1.udpate()
   //or to be more specific:
   Object.keys(e).forEach(key, function(){
     r1.update(key)
   })
})
```

@Rich_Harris took this concept a bit further and [created a Ractive adapter](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/Ractive-plugins/blob/master/adaptors/Ractive.js):

```
var r2 = new Ractive({ el:.., template:..., 
    data: r1,
    adapt: ['Ractive'] })
```

There are still some holes with bidirectional support for arrays, but it's a good start.

If you don't need IE8 support and all your browsers support defineProperty, you can use magic mode:

```
var data = { text:'Old Text'};

var r1 = new Ractive({ data:data, magic: true })
r1.observe('text', function(value){
    console.log('r1 says', value)
});

var r2 = new Ractive({ data:data, magic: true })
r2.observe('text', function(value){
    console.log('r2 says', value)
});

r2.set('text', 'New Text')

data.text = 'Yep, this works too'
```

Lastly, you might consider up-levelling Ractive and have it be a parent of these two views as components:

```
<div>
  <r1-component data="{{.}}"/>
  <r2-component data="{{.}}"/>
</div>
```

(However your layout goes). Oftentimes I've found this works best because there ends up being some top-level interaction that Ractive helps manage anyway.